# HashiCorp Vault error running as production

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to run Vault production mode in a Windows Machine but for some reason I'm getting the following error(picture below).
The following is my config.hcl file

```
storage "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path    = "vault/"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address     = "127.0.0.1:8080"
 tls_disable = 1
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running Consul server on `127.0.0.1:8500`? In the `config.hcl` you defined a Consul as the `storage` for Vault, so Vault is trying to connect to it, but the connection is refused as if there is nothing acceting connections on `127.0.0.1:8500`. You will need to configure and run Consul as well, if you plan to use it as storage backend.

Comment: thanks man, will try to run consul